# Get exif location data from HEIC

Tags: android, ios, cordova, exif, exif-js

I am developing an app using cordova, I can get the location data from all JPEG files but when I am trying to get the location from a HEIC file all exif information are stripped even though I get the file as JPEG (so it's automatically converted already form HEIC when reading the result from the input field). This is happening on all iOS 12 devices, but working perferctly in the Simulator (iOS12) meaning I can see the location data in HEIC files. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?